# How to obtain all ProductTypes created in my commercetools project?

Tags: java, commercetools, sphere.io

I need to obtain all the ProductType that have been defined in my commercetools project because I have to use the localized value of the "name" to perform a search in a file system.
Basically I need to use the JVM SDK to extract the list of ProductTypes and traverse it.

Can someone give me some clue how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep it is pretty feasible using the jvm sdk, here is a code snippet of how to do it

```
package io.sphere.sdk.deletemeplese;

import io.sphere.sdk.producttypes.ProductType;
import io.sphere.sdk.producttypes.queries.ProductTypeQuery;
import io.sphere.sdk.queries.PagedQueryResult;
import io.sphere.sdk.test.IntegrationTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class SomeIntegrationTest extends IntegrationTest {


    @Test
    public void test(){

        final int PAGE_SIZE = 500;
        final long totalProductTypes = client().executeBlocking(ProductTypeQuery.of().withLimit(0)).getTotal();

        List<ProductType> allProductTypes = IntStream.range(0,(int)(totalProductTypes/PAGE_SIZE) +1)
                .mapToObj(i->i)
                .map(i -> ProductTypeQuery.of().withLimit(500).withOffset(i*PAGE_SIZE))
                .map(client()::executeBlocking)
                .map(PagedQueryResult::getResults)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        assertThat(allProductTypes).hasSize((int)totalProductTypes);

    }

}
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your solution. I've tested it and works fine. I have eliminated the part of the limit of 500 in the offset since in my project I only have 6 types of product and it was not necessary.
Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the class [QueryExecutionUtils](http://commercetools.github.io/commercetools-jvm-sdk/apidocs/io/sphere/sdk/queries/QueryExecutionUtils.html).

```
CompletionStage<List<ProductType>> allProductTypesStage = 
       QueryExecutionUtils.queryAll(client, ProductTypeQuery.of());
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have never used that class, but I will try it in the future. It seems very powerful and versatile.